# Container width fits his children width

Tags: html, css

maybe this is a silly question, but I can't solve on my own.
I have a container (a div) which contains some other elements (example paragraphs, images and so on).
I want to assign a value to the container's width in order to center it in the page. (the default behaviour makes the container's width 100%, so I can't center it)
I have found a lot of posts talking about how to make the child element's width fit the container's one, but the only way I know to do the reverse is by using javascript (I want to avoid this).

Is there any way to do this by css?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the code you are using, until now?

Comment: You will probably need to use "float" to expand parent according to children.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question, but if you float the element it will take it's children's width and height `float:left` or `float:right` but you will probably need to center it using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, but I know of this solution, but how I wrote I'd like to avoid the use of JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I do not understand you correctly.

You have a div with child elements of unknown width and want the div to be centered.

As Billy Moat has stated, you can achieve this by adding a parent div with "text-align:center" as css property.

You do not need to add a fixed width to the div-to-be-centered; instead, add

```
display:inline-block;
```

to this div. The div will now be centered and take the width of the child elements.

Comment: You can go with `display: inline`, that works too.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDsFH/)  +1

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly then here's what you need to do.

You need a container DIV outside the DIV you've already mentioned with "text-align:center" set on it.

Then the inside DIV should have a set width on it and also have "margin-left:auto" and "margin-right:auto" on it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This won't get the desired results - by setting a fixed width, you prevent the child elements from setting the div width.  It needs to be inline or inline block to take on the child width.  The container with text-align:center will then center it.